# How to make Windows Explorer release focus on a file in selected and highlighted like the "open containing folder" action in search results

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, hyperlink

I want to  type a command in RUN or make a hyperlink to focus on a specific file (among so many files)  in the folder in a highlighted figure like when you mouse over the file or when you click the "open containing folder" action in search results.

Example:

```
"D:\new_folder\1.txt"
```

this command only opens the file, but I don't want to open it. I just want the file be selected...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe calling explorer with the select argument, `explorer.exe /select,"C:\folder\file.xyz"`, should do this for you.

To use this in Excel:

Create a hyperlink referring to the same cell the link is in:

[image]

Then in the VBA editor, add this to the Sheet containing the hyperlink:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$E$3" Then
    Shell "explorer.exe /select,""C:\Users\Jonno\Documents\Test\New folder\Test.xlsx""", vbNormalFocus
End If

End Sub
```

[image]

Clicking it will then open an explorer window with a file highlighted. You can change this to use the value *in* the cell as a file if needed, or when you click any hyperlink they're handled the same way by removing the IF statement.

Comment: For reference: [Command-Line Switches for Windows Explorer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/130510)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your working answer, this method solved my problem to some extend, but it is not useful when using as a hyperlink.(e.g. in Excel,...)

Comment: @Alireza_frm You could use VBA and the `Shell` command to launch an external program with the arguments.

Comment: would you give me an example, please?

Comment: @Alireza_frm Added an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jonno. how can I implement such this code in PowerPoint?